# How could Gandalf become the White and Saruman have no colour?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In *The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers* Gandalf cast Saruman out of the order; he had become the White. How could  Saruman have no colour? What is the requirement for being White in the order and what is the crime for which someone can lose his colour in the council?